# How to disable laptop power key in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, acpi, xfce4-power-manager, gallium

I have a Lenovo 100s chromebook with Lubuntu 16.04.1 installed over Gallium.
 The power key is where a delete key normally goes and sometimes while I'm typing I accidentally hit it and at least twice now I've coincidentally hit the enter key just as the logout popup came up and shut down my computer.
I'm using XFCE power manager and have the "when power button is pressed" setting set to "do nothing" and it doesn't work.
I've followed https://superuser.com/questions/699905/change-behavior-of-linux-power-button and changed "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" and "/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn" as suggested and deleted all of the text in "/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh", and rebooted and it didn't help.
If I can't disable the power key I'm thinking I could settle for a workaround where opening the logout popup menu would require root permission, but I don't know how to do that or even if it would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually lubuntu has a keybing in the default window manager openbox that brings up the quit dialog. You will need to edit  ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml . IT is good practice to make a backup of this file as it has all your keyboard shortcuts in it and can mess things up with cp ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml-old

and remove the lines

`<keybind key="XF86PowerOff">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>lxsession-default quit</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
  </keyboard>`

save the file and run `openbox --reconfigure` to have openbox use your new configuration.

Comment: Thank you!  But instead of deleting the lines I commented them out, is that bad practice?

Comment: No it has the same effect.